# Storing and printing consecutive characters in a String?

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, char

the task is to store consecutive characters in a List. Main with Input/Output looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> blocks = blocks("Hello faaantastic world");
    System.out.println(blocks); // => ["ll", "aaa"]
    System.out.println(blocks("aaabccdeeeefaaa")); // => ["aaa", "cc", "eeee", "aaa"]
    System.out.println(blocks("This is an example")); // => []
    System.out.println(blocks("Another  example ...")); // => [" ", "..."]
    System.out.println(blocks("")); // => []
```

My method looks like this:

```
public static LinkedList<String> blocks(String s) {
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    String word = "";
    
    for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == ??) {
            
        }
    }
        
    return list;
```

the String word is used to store consecutive letters. I found the toCharArray, to split each character of the String. But I have a problem with the if-block. If I do c == c+1 to check I and the following character of I, it's not working...I don't know how to solve this problem. Can someone help me? trying to solve it for 2 days now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it may be preferable to use `String::charAt` method to retrieve characters in the input string and their comparing to previous character.

```java
public static LinkedList<String> blocks(String s) {
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();

    String word = "" + s.charAt(0);
    
    for(int i = 1, n = s.length(); i < n; i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i - 1)) {
            word += s.charAt(i);
        } else {
            if (word.length() > 1) {
                list.add(word);
            }
            word = "" + s.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    if (word.length() > 1) {
        list.add(word);
    }
        
    return list;
}
```

Test

```java
System.out.println(blocks("Hello faaantastic worlddd"));
```

Output

```
[ll, aaa, ddd]
```

---

A shorter solution is possible using a regular expression to find repeating characters `(.)\1+`:

```java
public static List<String> findConsecutive(String s) {
    return Pattern.compile("(.)\\1+").matcher(s).results() // Stream<MatchResult>
        .map(mr -> mr.group(0)) // 0 group contains repeated characters
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Test

```java
System.out.println(findConsecutive("Hello   faaantastic worlddd"));
```

Output

```
[ll,    , aaa, ddd]
```

Comment: @Marco, you may upvote and/or accept the answer if it has been helpful (see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways to write this code, but to fully use what you have done, just cache the prevChar so you can compare c with it. How to init prevChar is tricky, either to choose something not possible in the text, or add another bool variable to indicate you are working on the first char, or peek into the array to make sure prevChar is different from the 1st char.